# Boot Ubuntu from an external SATA HDD via USB

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios

I removed my HDD from my old laptop that just died. I want to back up the data on it onto the other laptop I turned to. So I bought a SATA-to-USB adapter to connect the old HDD. The BIOS of this other computer detects the HDD, so I set the boot priority accordingly. But upon rebooting, the BIOS loads the Windows 10 install on the laptop's internal HDD instead of the Ubuntu install on the external HDD.

The laptop I'm using is Dell Inspiron N4050 and the BIOS version is A05.

Any help please?

Comment: If BIOS, you need to install grub to MBR of external drive. IF UEFI, you need an ESP - efi system partition on external & grub installed to that. Post this: `sudo parted -l`  If one system is UEFI and drive is BIOS, you may have to turn on allow USB boot and turn off UEFI Secure Boot.

Comment: On most Dell computers you should be able to press F12 for a boot menu. HDD, USB -CD-ROM, ect. Select USB. Note that you must use this F12 for BIOS, before Windows starts.